# Asp.net Dropdownlist scrollable

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I have a dropdownlist in a row of gridview.

I want that dropdownlist have a scrollbar if ther are more than 5 items, but row of gridview should not grow.

Using

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_data" runat="server" Visible="false" onmousedown="this.size=5;"  ClientIDMode = "Static" >
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a scrollbar but row growing!!

Answer (score 1):

```
   <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  onmouseover="this.size=5;" onmouseout="this.size=1;"  style="max-height:100px; overflow:auto;">    
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>   
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>TextTextText</asp:ListItem>    
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: gridview's row grow onmouseover.... I need that items appear on top of row, like dropdownlist usually does. I need that items appear in a overlapped div

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of a GridView row in your markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="yourGridViewID" ...>
    <RowStyle Height="20px" />
```

Or in code:

```
yourGridViewID.RowStyle.Height = "20px";
```

You could also just add a CssClass:

```
<RowStyle CssClass="myRowStyle" />
```

...and apply whatever styles you like in the stylesheet:

```
.myRowStyle { display:inline-block; height: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think putting the DropDownList in a fixed-height `<div>` in the GridView column (you'll have to use a TemplateField) will work. Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
  <TemplateField>
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
      <asp:DropDownList ...>
    </div>
  </TemplateField>
  ...
</asp:GridView>
```